# Not logging PHP errors on windows IIS server

Tags: php, iis, plesk

We're running an IIS website on a dedicated windows server which has Plesk 12 on it. We're having trouble getting PHP scripts to log any errors they encounter. In the php.ini we have tried setting both `error_log="C:/Inetpub/vhosts/site_name/logs/php_errors.txt"` and `error_log="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\site_name\logs\php_errors.txt"`. We have also set `error_reporting=E_ALL` and `log_errors=1`. When checking phpinfo() these changes are shown. Finally we have made sure the correct users have read/write permissions on the text file.

Any ideas why it isn't logging?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the reason in permissions.

Provide permission for Application pool group (IWPG_) for your log file

You can do it in "File Manager":
[image: plesk-file-manager-add-permissions-1.png]

[image: plesk-file-manager-add-permissions-2.png]

[image: plesk-file-manager-add-permissions-3.png]

*JFYI there is also "Additional read/write permission" on domains hosting settings, it's affects whole "httpdocs" folder*

Answer (score 0):

Better is to call the file "php_errors.log" and put it into the log directory used by the server for the access log (i.e. "W3SVC6"). In this way you can see the log in plesk with all standard log features.